# Translation( Module Level ) is not working when I don't use translate.use in feature components (Lazy Loaded)

Tags: angular8, ngx-translate

I have a angular 8 application and I use ngx-translate with module level translation. But when I do not use "translate.use('en')" the transaltions are not working in feature modules which is loaded by lazy loading .

```
export function Loader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, i18n + '/hooks/', '.json');
}
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(sitesRoutes),
      SharedModule,
      TranslateModule.forChild({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (Loader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
        },
      })
    ],
    declarations: [
        HooksComponent
    ]
  })
  export class HooksModule { }
```

---

```
private translateLanguage(): void {
     this._translate.use(this.language);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.translateLanguage();
}
```

The above code is working but this is a feature module loaded by lazy loading and it is loading from i18n/hooks/ but in app component also am using translate.use() ,I dont want to use in multiple places.

Comment: Same issue here...